# Outsource direct Ajax Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a little html page where I have a field which is for file upload and a input field which is filled by javascript ajax function on same page:

```html
<div class="input-group>
 <label>
  <span>Select 
   <input type="file" name="file" style="display: none;">
  </span>
 </label>
 <input type="text" readonly>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $(document).on('change', ':file', function() 
        {
            var input = $(this),           
            label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
            input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
        });

        $(document).ready( function() 
        {
            $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, label) 
            {

                var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
                log = label;

                if( input.length ) {
                    input.val(log);
                } else {
                    if( log ) alert(log);
                }

            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

I want to move the script from my index.html to my script.js file but it doesn't work. I guess it has something to do with not knowing things like $(document) and so on. I am not a javascript expert and need a little help with this.

Comment: A \*.js file on a html page will know what `$(document)` is.  The script runs on the page, and `document` exists on the page.  It *is* the page.  You just have to make sure the script is included after the jQuery include, so the \*.js knows what `$` is.

Comment: Also side note; `$(function() {});` and `$(document).ready(function(){});` are the same thing.  So you have a ready nested in a ready, which is unnecessary

Comment: Yeah ok I thought of that! But in the standalone .js how do I address the document, better, how do I make the script run?

Comment: If the script runs with it in the page, pulling it out into a js file and including that js file where the script originally was, should not cause the script to not run.  Otherwise, you need to show us the non working version.

Comment: Ok, maybe the problem was, I didn't include it on the spot where it originally was but in the html head. Now it should work but I would prefer having the script in the head, can I manage this somehow?

Comment: So long as it is included after the jQuery include, should work.

Comment: Also, can I name the functions somehow, because when I add a second ```$(function(){}); ```it only runs the second function

Comment: It is included last in my head and doesn't work

Comment: No, not two of them, a different function for another problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean then.  Can you share what you are trying to do?

Comment: I just run two ```$(function(){});``` for two different input fields and they get in conflict with each other

Comment: They should not conflict, which is why I asked that you show what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah, forget it. Didn't work because the second one opens ```<?php ?>``` to set some php variables